# Angular: Trying to display an asset image in an img src inside an iframe gives 404

Tags: javascript, angular

In my application I have an  element in which I load initially for its src a preview image, so it doesn't look broken in the page when it is initially loaded and nothing was assigned to it yet.

```
<img id="preview" src="./../../../../assets/transparent-3.png" alt="" class="image-preview-box" />
```

As you can see the src points to the angular assets folder, where it takes the transparent-3.png and fills the img with it. This works well when I run the code with "ng serve", the image loads all right.

But on deploy the application is deployed inside an iframe, since it needs to be part of a bigger application. In there the src doesn't work anymore and I receive the following error in the console, the img not loading the preview image.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I already tried to point directly to assets (without the dots and slashes before it) or to not use the ./ at the beginning of the src, yet it didn't work. Does anyone know what could be the issue in here?

Comment: try only `assets/transparent-3.png` path.

Comment: This worked, I realized when I did it first time I used /assets/transparent-3.png so that's why it didn't work. Thank you very much :D .

Comment: happy coding :)